# ¿Ya no gano reputación cuando edito alguna pregunta o respuesta?

Tags: discusión, ediciones-sugeridas

Vuelvo por el meta con otra duda.

Cuando empecé en esSO, una de las cosas que hacía, desde que me lo permitía mi reputación, era la edición de preguntas y/o respuestas.

Cuando hacía esto mi edición se quedaba en espera para ser revisada y aparecía cuando alguien aprobaba dicha edición. Entonces sumaba 2 puntos en mi reputación.

Ahora, al tener más privilegios para editar, mis ediciones no pasan por revisión, sino que aparecen de inmediato, pero ya no sumo 2 puntos, ni ningún punto, por editar preguntas.

No es lo que lo hacía por interés, pienso seguir contribuyendo a que el contenido de esSO sea de mejor calidad, pero me queda la duda de por qué ya no sumo esos dos puntitos.

Saludos.

Comment: Relacionado: http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1520/227

Comment: http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Al obtener 1,000 (mil) puntos de reputación ganaste el privilegio de moderación, editar preguntas y respuestas automáticamente, y "perdiste" el ganar puntos por cada edición aceptada.

Referencia: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation, chapó aldanux

> una edición sugerida es aceptada: +2 (hasta +1000 en total por usuario)

Comment: Gracias. Para que queda claro, ¿podrías citar la fuente y dejar el enlace en esSO donde lo afirma? Estuve buscando y no lo encontré. Saludos.

Comment: ¿A qué se debe la petición, escepticismo, perfeccionismo, ...?

Comment: Simplemente para que la respuesta quede más documentada. Y porque me extraña que no aparezca, o al menos no lo he visto, en SO. No es escepticismo, de hecho funciona como has dicho en la respuesta.

Comment: Si no lo has encontrado tal vez no exista. En cualquier caso, no te digo que no lo voy a agregar, sólo que habiendo tantas cosas sin documentar en español, tal vez no sea lo siguiente que haga.

Comment: Me acabo de dar cuenta que aldanux agregó el link :)

Comment: Ok. Gracias. Así la respuesta queda más completa, sin demasiado esfuerzo. Saludos :)